# how to close a window(JS file1) from another window's(JS file2) click event in Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I have created an App using Titanium appcelerator. Here i have 3 JS files with seperate "Window" for each. Is it possible to close the 2nd JS file's "window", when i click on a button in 3rd JS file. 
I have tried it by passing 2nd Window name to 3rd JS file & then close it on button click event,but it didn't worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write this in window where button is

```
Ti.App.fireEvent('customEvent', nil);
```

And this in which window is to be closed

```
Ti.App.addEventListener('customEvent', function()
{
   window.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a simple way. Try the following code.

*I'm assuming that you're currently in the second window*

**win2.js**

```
var win2 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : '#123456'
});

var btnNewWindow = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title   : 'Open new window'
});

btnNewWindow.addEventListener('click', function(){

    var win3 = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        backgroundColor : '#abcdef',
        _previousWindow : Ti.UI.currentWindow,
        url     : 'win3.js' 
    });

    win3.open();
});

win2.add(btnNewWindow);
win2.open();
```

**win3.js**

```
var win3 = Ti.UI.currentWindow;

var btnClosePrevious = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title   : 'Close previous Window'
});

btnClosePrevious.addEventListener('click', function(){

    win3._previousWindow.close();
});

win3.add(btnClosePrevious);
```

Here I have passed the previous window as parameter instead of name of previous window. It's a window object and when you call the close method of previousWindow, it will close the window.

I have tried it, it will work.

Hope it helped you

Comment: Thanks for the help Anand. But i not using this method to navigation. I am using "require" method. So fireevent solves my problem.